# Dynamically build a unicode characters?

Tags: python

How can I dynamically output the correct unicode number given this dictionary:

```
UNICODE_CHARS = {
        0: "\u2070",
        1: "\u00B9",
        2: "\u00B2",
        3: "\u00B3",
        4: "\u2074",
        5: "\u2075",
        6: "\u2076",
        7: "\u2077",
        8: "\u2078",
        9: "\u2079",
    }
```

Eg: The number 177 would be:

`print(f"{UNICODE_CHARS.get(1)}{UNICODE_CHARS.get(7)}{UNICODE_CHARS.get(7)}")`

How would I construct this in a loop?

```
for i in range(1000):
    # how to print each number here with unicode? Up until 9 is easy
    # eg UNICODE_CHARS.get(i), but after 9 it gets tricky, and with 2, 3, or 4 digits even harder 
    print(....)
```

Comment: Loop through all the digits: `print(''.join(UNICODE_CHARS[int(d)] for d in str(i)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should change your mapping from Char -> Char (instead of int -> Char).

Then you convert your number (i) to a string and build a list of mapped characters for each "digit" in your string.

Then you convert the list to a string again by using "".join

Complete example:

```
UNICODE_CHARS = {
    "0": "\u2070",
    "1": "\u00B9",
    "2": "\u00B2",
    "3": "\u00B3",
    "4": "\u2074",
    "5": "\u2075",
    "6": "\u2076",
    "7": "\u2077",
    "8": "\u2078",
    "9": "\u2079",
}

for i in [1, 9, 123, 177]:
    print("".join([UNICODE_CHARS[c] for c in str(i)]))
```

Output:

```
¹
⁹  
¹²³
¹⁷⁷
```

I've change your `range` into a list, but it's the same with range.

Comment: Thanks! Why char over int though?

Comment: @erikvm because we're converting the number ``i`` to a string and then we're mapping each character of that string to another character. If the dict keys were integers, we would have to convert each character back to an int first - like Johnny Mopp did in the comments to your question. By using characters as dict keys we can save us this integer conversion.